# iOS 15 Product Page Optimization info in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, ab-testing

I set up Product Page Optimization on Appstore connect. I have 3 treatments and three different app icons, I want to ask can I get the current treatment name in swift so I can change app theme color accordingly?

Thanks,